# Issue with ActionScript EventListeners

Tags: actionscript-3, event-listener

I'm trying to put 2 functions on 1 event.
By the click of the left mouse button you can make the visibility of a square go false and true. However it only works once. It disappears at the first click and it reappears at the second click. After that it no longer works. How do I make it so it constantly reads the code even after being used?
Here's my code:

```
var poop = true;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dissappearsquare)
function dissappearsquare(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
if(poop == true)
{
square2.visible = false;
poop = false;
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dissappearsquare1)
function dissappearsquare1(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
if(poop == false)
{
    square2.visible = true;
    poop = true;
}
 }
 }
 }
```

I hope I supplied enough information , thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having two EventListener, you get them executed both, so that one *overrides* the action of the other.

You only need one, and much more simple:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dissappearsquare)
function dissappearsquare(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
     square2.visible = !square2.visible
}
```

that means:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dissappearsquare)
function dissappearsquare(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
     if (square2.visible == true) {
         square2.visible = false
     }
     else if (square2.visible == false) {
         square2.visible = true
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Could you perhaps explain why square2.visible = !square2.visible works the way it does? Thank you again, it works as intended now.

Comment: `square2.visible = !square2.visible` means toggle the visibility of `square2`. If `square2.visible` is `true` it will assign NOT `true`, and viceversa.